# What happens to a person's frontal lobes when they have a breakdown from stress?

Tags: stress, frontal-lobes

When a person gets really stressed out and has a mental breakdown what happens to their frontal lobes?

I'm reminded of the clip from ["What about Bob?"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103241/) when Richard Dreyfuss has a breakdown when he learns that Bill Murray is marrying his sister, and then he ends up in the home basket weaving for a couple of months as an example of this...

Comment: I'd suggest changing the question to something akin to "what are the neural correlates of a mental breakdown" or even "Is a mental breakdown detectable at the neural level?" The current question presupposes the lobe granularity is the right one, which we shouldn't accept without some cited research.

Comment: I have stress reactions to noise. A little brandy numbs the front of my brain and i relax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Research would suggest that the type of "incessant" or "severe" stress required to precipitate a  "breakdown" would the higher cognitive functions performed within the frontal lobes.  As I am unsure what level of understanding you are requiring on this topic, I have included suitable quotes from a relevant study, which provides the answer to your question.

I quote Amy F. T. Arnsten's study of the effects of stress on the frontal lobe:

> The prefrontal cortex (PFC)—the most evolved brain region—subserves
>   our highest-order cognitive abilities. However, it is also the brain
>   region that is most sensitive to the detrimental effects of stress
>   exposure. Even quite mild acute uncontrollable stress can cause a
>   rapid and dramatic loss of prefrontal cognitive abilities, and more
>   prolonged stress exposure causes architectural changes in prefrontal
>   dendrites. Recent research has begun to reveal the intracellular
>   signalling pathways that mediate the effects of stress on the PFC.
>   This research has provided clues as to why genetic or environmental
>   insults that disinhibit stress signalling pathways can lead to
>   symptoms of profound prefrontal cortical dysfunction in mental
>   illness.

Within the conclusion:

> The detrimental effects of stress on PFC networks are particularly
>   problematic in the ‘information age’, when PFC-mediated cognitive
>   abilities are increasingly needed for success. understanding the
>   molecular mechanisms that alter PFC structure and impair PFC function
>   during stress exposure will help to reveal how genetic and
>   environmental insults can increase an individual’s susceptibility to
>   PFC deficits. Identifying the molecular mechanisms that alter PFC
>   function will provide the foundation for a new era in psychiatry, when
>   we will understand how genetic changes affect intracellular
>   signalling, neural development and neurophysiology in the circuits
>   that underlie neuropsychiatric symptoms. It is hoped that this
>   information will provide the framework for therapies aimed at
>   rectifying molecular errors and ameliorating the symptoms of mental
>   illness.

[Stress signalling pathways that impair prefrontal cortex structure and function](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2907136/)
Amy F. T. Arnsten
Nat Rev Neurosci. 2009 June; 10(6): 410–422.
doi:  10.1038/nrn2648